# Bootbox change title css

Tags: javascript, css, bootbox

For my project I want different pop-ups for different useage. So I created a new css class. Now I want to change the style of the title component (as shown below) on the same way as I changed the buttons.

So my question is: can I change the css of the title the same way as I change the css of the buttons? With the `className` property. Also, how should I do that?

```
bootbox.dialog({
    message: "<h4>" + errorMessage + "<h4>",
    title: $filter("translate")("Warning"),
    buttons: {
        no: {
            label: $filter("translate")("Cancel"),
            className: "c-btn-declined-selection c-btn-global-warning",
            callback: noCallback
        },
        yes: {
            label: $filter("translate")("Confirm"),
            className: "c-btn-confirm-selection c-btn-global-warning",
            callback: yesCallback
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest opening the page in a browser. When the box comes up, right click it, do an Inspect Element, and see what classes/items are generated. You can style those using basic CSS instead of doing it through JavaScript.

Comment: You are right about that. But i use the bootbox for different purposes. So i'd rather want to create a custom style for it. It is possible with the buttons, so i wonder if it is possible for the title as well on the same way.

Comment: While I'm not too familiar with bootbox, a quick inspection of their documentation shows that the only option that's an object is `buttons`, whereas most others (including `title`) are `strings.

Comment: really? I totally missed that when i was looking for information on the bootbox. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If the title element accepts HTML, could you not just do something like `title: "<span style='color: red; font-size: 24px;'>This is a test!</span>"`, or even just `title: "<span class="myCustomTitle">This is a test!</span>"`?

Comment: Yeah i found something like that too, was just testing that out! It seems to work till some point, gonna try that. You can put it as the answer, I will mark it as correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the [Bootbox.js documentation](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#options), it seems that an inherent title-styling method doesn't exist. This leaves you with two options...

---

**1. Add the style/class in-line:**

```
bootbox.dialog({
    //...
    title: "<span style='color: red;'>This title is red</span>",
    //...
})
```

```
bootbox.dialog({
    //...
    title: "<span class="redText">This title is red</span>",
    //...
})
```

---

**2. Manipulate the generated elements manually**

Right click your Bootbox dialog on the page and go to *Inspect Element*. From here you'll see the generated content, including classes and elements, from which you can just use some basic CSS rules to style them.

For example, if the pop-up HTML looked like this...

```
<div class='bootbox-popup'>
    <h4 class='popup-title'></h4>
    <div class='popup-body'> ... </div>
</div>
```

You could style it using something like:

```
h4.popup-title {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: There is a `className` option that gets applied to the whole dialog ([example](http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#also-applies-to-confirm-prompt-custom%0A%0Acustom-css-class)), and that can be used to style the title using a descendant selector.